# Customer confirmation email resend

Tags: register, confirmation

How to resend the customer confirmation email  (Register) through admin panel?
Is there any options for resending?.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is no default option in magento to resend a account creation email. But you can achieve this by:

Rewrite the block class`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit` and add a new button in the constructor:

```
if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
    $this->_addButton('resendemail', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Resend Confimation Email'),
        'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('yourmodule/customer/resendEmail', array('customer_id' => $this->getCustomerId())) . '\')',
    ), 0);
}
```

Create your own custom controller action:

```
public function resendEmailAction() {
    $customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id', false);
    if ($customerId) {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmation', '', $customer->getStoreId());
        } else {
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $customer->getStoreId());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/customer');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have add the above code and confirmation email send successfully. But while click on the confirmation button on email, show as "Bad request"

Comment: What is the url of that button?

Comment: This is url confirmation link button. http://www.domain.com/customer/account/confirm/?back_url=&id=176

Comment: `registered` will use the email template which has a confirmation key in it, and your configuration (`System >> Configuration >> Customer >>  Require Emails Confirmation` = `Yes` for this.

Comment: try the updated answer

Comment: I have already set this value as "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$id = 3;
$customer = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($id);
$confirmation = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotificationInterface');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$email = $customer->getEmail();
$accountMangement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement');
$accountMangement->resendConfirmation($email,1);
echo "done";
```